# Find the sum of the digits of the number

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

[image]

Obviously, $a_1 \ne 0$ and $a_1 \ge 1$.

$$N = 10^n a_1 + 10^{n-1} a_2 + \cdots + 10^0 a_n$$

But I dont think I can do a lot more.

Answer (score 3):

$9a_k=10(a_k-1)+(10-a_k)$.
Now work out the carries, and see what cancels.